# Javascript set translate with scroll event is slow

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem when setting `transform: translateY();` based on scroll event `value`.

basically, `#moveme` will disappering while scroll event trigger.

check this fiddle out for live action : https://jsfiddle.net/bo6e0wet/1/

here is the code :

**HTML**

```
<div id="moveme"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {

  var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();  

  if (currentScroll <= 50) {

    $("#moveme").css("transform", "translate3d(0," + -currentScroll + "px, 0");

  }

});
```

why did `moveme` not diappering totally? is it because scroll event fires too much, so the DOM did not get it quickly?

i try scrollng very slow, with my touch pad. it's working perfect.

**but** if i press `CTRL + DOWN ARROW` which mean force to scroll to down of the page. `moveme` stuck.

how to solve this problem?

what's wrong with my code?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this condition:

```
if (currentScroll <= 50)
```

to something higher, like

```
if (currentScroll <= 75)
```

because the `currentScroll` jumps from 39 to 65, so it misses the 50 point, and only translates -39 [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70u7v4wy/);

Comment: thanks Ori for ansering, i'm really apreciate that. had u try with `CTRL + DOWN ARROW" ? still stucked.

Comment: i feel like using 75 is not really relevant method. because when someone with touch screen try with scroll to down quickly ,it will cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop(); 
  if ($(currentScroll <= 50)) {
    $("#moveme").css("transform", "translate3d(0," + -currentScroll + "px, 0");
  }
});
```

```css
#moveme { width: 100%; height: 50px; background: red;
          position: fixed; top: 0; left:0; color: #FFF; }
#box { height: 1000px; background-color: #F1F1F1; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="moveme">
  i will disappering. wait?! why there is a gap there?
  i'm not totally disappeared. what's wrong here?
</div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

For some reason this small adjustment seems to work

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();    
    if ($(currentScroll <= 50)) {
        $("#moveme").css("transform", "translate3d(0," + -currentScroll + "px, 0");
    }
});
```